# QOpenGLWidget linker error with QT example code

Tags: c++, qt, linker-errors, apple-m1

after several failed attempts to create a QOpenGLWidget.I tried to run the QT example code https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/opengl/2dpainting?h=5.15
But that does not work too. I get the same vtable error as in the previous attempts. Here is the complete error code.

[image: error code]

I already reinstalled QT and added

```
QT += core gui widgets opengl

LIBS += -framework OpenGL -framework QtOpenGL -framework GLUT
```

to the .pro file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Qt6, then you need to link against `openglwidgets`.

See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopenglwidget.html